# Breadth-first search in MySQL using a large amount of data

Tags: mysql, recursion

I have access to a MYSQL table in a mariadb server. The table 'ggLink' organizes information in the basic format of gene source and gene target as columns. We assume that every edge is unitary.

Say column named gene1 is the target, and gene2 is the source. Say that we want to find a path from our source, gene2='MTOR' to our target gene1='IFIT1'.

I want to implement a depth first search from the source to the target, and preferably something with an upper path limit so it terminates if the process gets way out of hand. To explain the data a bit consider the simple query:

```
SELECT gene1 FROM ggLink WHERE gene2='MTOR'; #gene2 is source
```

Output

> gene1:
> ABCA1..FOX1..IL10.. (610 other target genes)

IL10 is then used in a recursive query:

```
SELECT gene1 FROM ggLink WHERE gene2='IL10';
```

Output:

> gene1: A2M..CRK..IFIT1` (600 other genes)

Here we achieved the path MTOR-IL10-IFIT1. I would like all paths that terminate in our target. In my approach I'm preventing the reoccurrence of loops and tracking the path variable. I'm also putting an upper limit of 3 on the maximum recursion depth.

Keep in mind that this is run on MariaDB server that's not fully up to date so it doesn't include an inbuilt LIMIT for recursive cte's. :

```
set @start_node='MTOR';
set @end_node = 'IFIT1';

WITH RECURSIVE paths(path, last, level) AS (
  SELECT json_array(@start_node, gene1), gene1, 0 as level
  FROM ggLink
  WHERE gene2=@start_node
  UNION ALL
  SELECT json_array_append(path, '$', gene1), gene1, level+1
  FROM ggLink
  JOIN paths on gene2 = last
  WHERE (not json_contains(path, json_quote(gene1)) AND level<3)
)
SELECT path FROM paths where last = @end_node;
```

This method gives all destination paths, except cycles by creating a path column and breaking when it sees something already in the path.

I would also appreciate if you could break down your solution for me to help increase my understanding of complex SQL queries. Currently, my code does not terminate even with a max recursion limit of 2. I want to know if there is a problem with my current code, or if this task is simply too complex.

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output, so it can be easy to help